# Trying to render :partials instead of whole views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get some simple toggles to render small partials instead of changing the whole view - I'm not clear whether this is considered AJAX or not... anyway.

Here we have the user answering a question. While doing this, the question itself can be flagged as inappropriate.

View: `answers#new.html.erb`
Partial in view: `_flag.html.erb`
Controller for toggle: `opinions/flag`, which is supposed to update the `opinion` and render the `flag` partial inside the current `answers#new`.

```
# flag.html.erb
<% if @opinion.try(:flag) == true %>
    <b>Flagged.</b>
    <%= link_to "undo", opinions_flag_url(:id => @question.id, :flag => false), :remote => true %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "flag this", opinions_flag_url(:id => @question.id, :flag => true), :remote => true %>
<% end %> 

# last part of opinions controller / flag
if @opinion.save
    format.html { render :partial => "answers/flag" }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
else
    format.html { render :action => "new", :id=>params[:id] }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @opinion.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

The partial is rendered, but **not inside the current view** (it's displayed on a blank page). In general, how do I render bits and pieces to the current view without Rails assuming it needs to show me the partial by itself?

Corollary: If I want to render text to a view, how do I specify where that new text will go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use rjs. If you aren't sure if you are using it, you probably aren't :)

In short, you should use **form_remote_for** instead of **form_for** and you should use this in your controllers.

```
respond_to do |format|
  ...
  format.js { Do stuff here }
end
```

Here's a screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs

The specific command to put some html in a specific place would be:

```
page.replace_html "SOME_HTML_ID", "<p>SOME_HTML</p>"
```

But once you've seen the screencast, that should be obvious :)